# Can't Optimize Huge Sprite Sheet in Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, memory-management, sprite, sprite-sheet

I was shocked to find that a game I had just created takes up a whopping 330 megabytes. According to the Editor Log, my textures are to blame:

[image]

From the list I started at the top with the Chieftain Walk animation spritesheet. The file was huge, so I opened it in Photoshop and decreased the image resolution dramatically.

[image]

However, even after saving in Photoshop, the Editor Log claims that the texture takes up the same amount of memory. What am I doing wrong, and also, when does the Editor Log update? Is it upon building the game? Many thanks.

Comment: did you create this sprite sheet or was it something you downloaded?

Comment: yes @RSon1234, I took the painful route of exporting frame by frame from Toonboom to a sprite gluing software and finally into Unity. Foolish choice on my part ha ha

Comment: * yes I created the puppet in Photoshop @RSon1234

Comment: are all of these separate textures?

Comment: no, its a single sprite sheet @RSon1234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to reduce resolution on the actual PNG file. When Unity builds player, it will store the imported uncompressed file in its Data folder near the executable. The size of the texture will be as it is in your importer settings. By default it is 2048x2048 if I remember correctly. If you change importer settings for your texture, the PNG file will remain the same (which is in the editor), but the texture object (which is used in actual standalone) will become much smaller.

Also, is there any particular reason why you didn't make it squared? Like 512x512. Always make it a square and a power of 2. If not, Unity will be unable to make any optimizations for your sprites

EDIT:

This is the texture import settings, set max size to lower and your game will take less memory (both in hard drive and in RAM/GPU when game is running). You can also add compression level, it will take even less memory, but will take longer to load (in game). When loaded will take same amount of RAM/GPU memory as non-compressed. A win on app size, a lose on load performance. (Test it out and choose what is better for you)

[image: This is the texture import settings]

Why power of 2 and square, well:

By ensuring the texture dimensions are a power of two, the graphics pipeline can take advantage of optimizations related to efficiencies in working with powers of two. For example, it can be faster to divide and multiply by powers of two. It will also be easier for unity to create mip-maps (they might take more memory if texture is not square). There are many sources on internet about mip-mapping.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what "Unity will be unable to make any optimizations for your sprites" means. What kind of optimizations? My apologies, I'm self taught and rather ignorant.

Comment: what steps specifically then should I take to decrease the file size of the texture object? I really appreciate your help

Comment: @DrakeTruber Yes, you must reduce resolution on your sprites. And they must be **Square and a power of 2**, (for example: 256x256, 512x512, 1024x1024 and etc.). If your `ChiefWalk.png`  not square, make it square. For mobile game i recommend use sprite size not more than 2048x2048. **If** your sprites in  `chiefWalk.png` spritesheet not fit in one squared(2048x2048) spritesheet, just split him to 2-3-4 spritesheets. And it simple way to reduce textures size.

Comment: You can test one thing, create white square (just white) in photoshop(or paint) with 1024x1024 resolution. You see, that file will take **~8KB** on hard disk. Then import this white square to unity and you will see, that texture will takes **2MB** (with compression) or **4MB** (true color) .

Comment: Thanks so much guys